# `getParentFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(0, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);` only works once

Tags: java, android

First of all, I'm pretty new to Android development.

I'm building an simple Android app with 1 Activity which contains 3 fragments.
Lets name the fragments `A`, `B` and `C`. Each fragment contains some input fields and a "next" button. The last fragment contains a "finish" button which sends the data (collected in the fragments) to an API and navigates to fragment `A` again to start over again.

In fragment `A` and `B`, i navigate to the next fragment by calling this function:

```
    private void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, someFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

This works fine so far. In fragment `C` i post the collected data to the API and call this code afterwards:

```
        FragmentManager fm = getParentFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStackImmediate(0, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

This works perfect but only once. After i'm "redirected" from fragment `C` to fragment `A` and go again via `B` to `C` and click `Finish` in fragment `C`, the mentioned code is triggered but I'm not redirected to `A` anymore.

When i kill the app and restart the app, it works once again. What I'm doing wrong?

---

**Update**
During debugging i can see that the `BackStack` is a list with `BackStackEntries`. This list always contains 2 entries when I'm in frament `C` and i thought `fm.popBackStackImmediate(0,...` "redirects" to entry 0 of the `BackStack`. Now i notice that each `BackStackEntry` has a property `mIndex` which is increasing all the time. Probably is the `id` parameter in the `popBackStackImmediate` not the position in the `BackStack` but refers to the `BackStackItem` its `mIndex`.

Is this true and if yes, how can i get the ID of the correct back stack item in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `id` in `fm.popBackStackImmediate(0, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);` is not the position of the `BackStackEntry` in the `BackStack` but the `id` of the `BackStackEntry`. This id is increasing never reused so its continuously increasing.

The `BackStackEntry` of fragment `A` is always on position `0` in my case so i can simply get its `id` like:
`Integer $homeFragmentBackStackId = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId();`

And than do:
`fm.popBackStackImmediate($homeFragmentBacStackId,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`